# jQuery 1.12 Tabs Widget: active tab based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery 1.12 Api and I would like to make active a tab based on its id.
Using jQuery 1.8 Api this was possible with this piece of code:

```
$('#div-container').tabs('select', '#' + idTab);
```

From what i read in the documentation, in 1.12 the closest way to achieve that is by doing:

```
$('#div-container').tabs( 'option', 'active', tabPosition);
```

But this, is not equivalent to the first piece of code..so i would like to know if there is an EQUIVALENT way in 1.12 to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tabPosition = $( '#' + idTab ).index() - 1;
$( '#div-container' ).tabs( 'option', 'active', tabPosition );
```

Comment: PS: Don't forget to define `idTab`.

Comment: .index() function is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load resize', function () {
            if (window.location.hash) {
                $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
            } else {
                $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show')
            }
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                window.location.hash = e.target.hash
            })
        });
    </script>
```

This worked for me in bootstrap tabs